# Need original file of Mint 13 for recovery

Tags: linux-mint

I messed up one file and I didn't do a backup. Someone could post the original file usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/windowAttentionHandler.js of Linux Mint 13 Maya?

Comment: You should be able to find out what package the file belonged, and reinstall that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file belongs to the package `gnome-shell-common`, as told by `apt-file` in a Mint 14 box. Try reinstalling this package.

Comment: Actually, I've just reinstalled the package "cinnamon" and it worked, thanks for the idea!